# how to open standard see inside view(street view ) in google map on my own android application

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Once user presses button in my application, I would like to open standard see inside view(same as street view) and to show particular business place in Google Map on my own android application.

i am try to intent parsing activity it is working only for street view places like taj mahal(latlong=27.173891,78.042068) india

```
 // intent activity(this activity call google map street view)
  Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=27.173891,78.042068" + "&cbp=1,90,,0,1.0&mz=8"));
  startActivity(streetView);

  // streetViewPanoramaFragment this method call inside my application
   StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
                (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
            streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);

            @Override   
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
     panorama.setPosition(new LatLng(27.173891,78.042068));
      long duration = 500;
         float tilt = 0;
         StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
             .zoom(panorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
             .bearing(panorama.getPanoramaCamera().bearing)
             .tilt(tilt)
             .build();

         panorama.animateTo(camera, duration);
         }
```

but this intent parsing method not working for see inside view places like kusal flora(latlong=13.0682879,80.2562338) at chennai. web [url](https://www.google.co.in/maps/@13.0682879,80.2562338,3a,75y,244.76h,89.23t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sZjE7TJumUFMAAAQW-bHrsA!2e0!3e2!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1?hl=en)

```
  Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=13.0682879,80.2562338" + "&cbp=1,90,,0,1.0&mz=8"));
  startActivity(streetView);
```

how to resolve this. 
  kindly post your ideas.thanks